# Pyomo load command error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: arrays, excel, load, pyomo

I am trying to load an array from an excel file. It can be successfully loaded into pyomo when the array size is of 10000 by 140. But I got an error when I was trying to load a 13000 by 140 array. In fact, any array which is larger than that will cause the same error. The error messages are as follows:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-aa9be177f58b> in <module>()
     63 
     64 data = DataPortal(model=model)
---> 65 data.load(filename='Input_L.xlsx', range='Table13000', format='array', param='xo')
     66 data.load(filename='lowx.xlsx' , range='Dtable', format='array', param='lowx')
     67 data.load(filename='upx.xlsx'  , range='Etable', format='array', param='upx')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\DataPortal.py in load(self, **kwds)
    155             logger.debug("Processing data ...")
    156         self._data_manager.read()
--> 157         status = self._data_manager.process(self._model, self._data, self._default)
    158         self._data_manager.clear()
    159         #

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\data\TableData.py in process(self, model, data, default)
     90           set=self.options.set,
     91           param=self.options.param,
---> 92           ncolumns = self.options.ncolumns)
     93 
     94     def clear(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\data\process_data.py in _process_data(cmd, _model, _data, _default, Filename_, Lineno_, index, set, param, ncolumns)
    928 
    929     elif cmd[0].startswith('param'):
--> 930         cmd = _preprocess_data(cmd)
    931         _process_param(cmd, _model, _data, _default, index=index, param=param, ncolumns=ncolumns)
    932 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\data\process_data.py in _preprocess_data(cmd)
    118                 raise ValueError("Unexpected ']' that does not follow a '['")
    119             else:
--> 120                 newcmd.append(_process_token(token))
    121 
    122         elif state == 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\data\process_data.py in _process_token(token)
     55         return False
     56 
---> 57     if token[0] == '[' and token[-1] == ']':
     58         vals = []
     59         token = token[1:-1]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am wondering if the array is too big to be loaded. The pyomo software is running in Anaconda in a PC of 8GB RAM.